# Ports are blocked: Can't install Docker Universal Control Plane on Ubuntu guest using VMware

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, firewall, dtr

I'm trying to install DCP (Docker Universal Control Plane) on a Ubuntu guest virtual machine on VMware (on a Windows 10 host, with bridged network) in order to install and use DTR (Docker Trusted Registery) on it.

This command

```
docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name ucp docker/ucp install -i --host-address 172.17.9.102
```

returns:

```
INFO[0000] Verifying your system is compatible with UCP 
INFO[0000] Your engine version 1.12.1, build 23cf638 (4.4.0-31-generic) is compatible 
Please choose your initial UCP admin password: 
Confirm your initial password: 
INFO[0007] All required images are present              
WARN[0007] None of the hostnames we'll be using in the UCP certificates [ubuntu 127.0.0.1 172.17.0.1 172.17.9.102] contain a domain component.  Your generated certs may fail TLS validation unless you only use one of these shortnames or IPs to connect.  You can use the --san flag to add more aliases 

You may enter additional aliases (SANs) now or press enter to proceed with the above list.
Additional aliases: 
INFO[0009] Installing UCP with host address 172.17.9.102 - If this is incorrect, please specify an alternative address with the '--host-address' flag 
INFO[0000] Checking that required ports are available and accessible 
FATA[0032] The following required ports are blocked on your host: 12385, 12383, 12376, 12379, 12384, 12381, 2376, 12382, 12386, 12380, 443.  Check your firewall settings.
```

So do you guys have a solution for this? Is it possible to open these ports only for the virtual machine? So, I mean having different 'firewall' settings than this?

PS. I think I'm not allowed to change firewall settings on the host OS (Windows 10).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already had docker 1.12 installed and you updated docker 1.12-cs engine on top of this.
Solution will be, you remove docker engine binary, install docker engine 1.12-cs2 again and try.